# SQL command how to append(insert) values into DB

Tags: java, sql, insert, playframework-2.0

my question is how to insert values into DB in sql. i have a USER who can have multiple emails. how can i insert multiple emails into one object? i dont want to add a completely new user object into a new row. i just want to update and append new email into email field of an existing user in db.

i did this:

```
JPA.em().createQuery
        ("insert into User (email) select (email) from User where USERNAME=? VALUES (?)")
        .setParameter(1, username).setParameter(2, email).executeUpdate();
```

but it is not working, thanks for help !!

Comment: how this behaves? Can you set "email" with two or more ID's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the user from the database, concatenate its existing email with the new value, and save the user.

JPA uses entities and generates SQL queries for you. You tyically use queries only to get entities from the database. And those queries are JPQL queries, not SQL queries.

And it looks like your schema is not normalized correctly. One User entity should have many Email entities (OneToMany associations), rather than stuffing all the emails in a single CLOB field of the user. This is how you could search and get individual emails from the database, and get users without all their emails if you don't need them.

Comment: Great, you taught me a new thing. i will annotate it as OneToMany but the code to concatinate looks how? :(

Comment: If you use an email entity and a OneToMany association, there is no concatenation anymore. The User entity has a collection of Email entities, stored in their own separate database table. You create a new instance, persist it, and add it to the collection of emails of the user. You really need to read a book or tutorial about JPA, because it's something you need to understand before coding.

Comment: i thought, one user object has an varchar column called 'email' and that column can have multpiple values. :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't know JPA but query should be

```
JPA.em().createQuery
        ("insert into User (email) select (email) from User where USERNAME=? VALUES (?)")
        .setParameter(1, username).setParameter(2, email).executeUpdate();
```

should be

```
JPA.em().createQuery("UPDATE User 
                      SET email =? 
                      WHERE USERNAME=? ")
                      .setParameter(1,email )
                      .setParameter(2,username)
                      .executeUpdate();
```

Comment: no, i am looking for the way to append and not set. one user should be able to have more emails, but if i set, old email will be overwritten and at the end of the day, user has only one email again..

Comment: @doniyor : Correct me if I am wrong. You have data in emial field as emialid001@ddd.com, emialid002@ddd.com, emialid003@ddd.com and you want to add new email id as emialid004@ddd.com so that your new data would be emialid001@ddd.com, emialid002@ddd.com, emialid003@ddd.com, emialid004@ddd.com

Comment: thank you for attemp, but lets say the user has initially only one email, now i want him to have 2 emails, and set will set the old one to new one, but user will still have one email.. anyway, JB Nizet's look sounds great..

Comment: @doniyor : You will first need to get the email id of that user, then concatenate new email id and then update the DB. Thats it... But you need to normalize your data. ***Keeping 2 emails in one field is bad design.***

Comment: oh okay, normalize means in my case that i should have another class Email with OneToMany association and then i can save multiple emails with same user id, right?

Comment: @doniyor : yes, new table would have field have userid, email with primary key as (userid,email) (this is called composite primary key) & email as unique key.

Comment: Okay. Great! many Thanks Fahim! let me try this.. i will leave feedback in a while here..